# Select and Insert in the same transaction to ensure uniqueness

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a booking solution that enables booking of facilities. We have to ensure a facility is not double booked. Whilst we have not had any double bookings to date I do not believe the current implementation ensures this.

If anybody can give advice on the best was to do this it would be appreciated. I would like a solution that avoids doing the insert then having to do another read to check that there is no overlap in the times.

EDITED: As it appears more detail is needed. In the query shown we do a SELECT and then an INSERT. I assume that there is a chance that between the SELECT (saying the time is available) and the INSERT (booking the time) another user could do a INSERT thus ending up with a double booking. I assume there is some way to wrap the SELECT and the INSERT in a transaction (although I have yet understand how the isolation levels work). The other factor is this is a multi-tenanted solution so I am worried that if wrapping the SELECT and INSERT in a transaction will need a table lock which will cause other performance problems.

Currently we do the insert using the following SQL. We basically do a select to see if the time is available, do the insert if it is, then return how many rows were changed to see if the insert succeeded.

```
INSERT INTO Bookings (TenantId, FacilityId, UnitId, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, ...)
SELECT @TenantId, @FacilityId, @UnitId, @StartDateTime, @EndDateTime, ...
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bookings WHERE TenantId = @TenantId AND FacilityId = @FacilityId AND
    ((StartDateTime >= @StartDateTime AND StartDateTime < @EndDateTime) OR (EndDateTime > @StartDateTime AND StartDateTime < @StartDateTime))) = 0; SELECT @@Identity AS [Identity], @@RowCount AS [RowCount]";
```

Comment: This depends on the isolation level and how you query. Using a CTE or a subquery can achieve part of what you want.

Comment: No table name on the second select SELECT as values?

Comment: @reds the query works. The question is about avoiding getting two INSERTS for the one FacilityId at the same booking time.

Comment: Use distinct to avoid duplication

Comment: Thanks @Clifton, I do think the answer might include transaction isolation levels but I am trouble find good docs on how the isolation level effects performance

Answer (score 0):

I think, using sub-queries always let slow down your query run time. 
To be honest, I am not sure about what you are trying to do but I can change a query like this.

```
INSERT INTO Bookings (TenantId, FacilityId, UnitId, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, ...)
SELECT @TenantId, @FacilityId, @UnitId, @StartDateTime, @EndDateTime, ...
LEFT JOIN Bookings b ON b.TenantId = @TenantId AND b.FacilityId = @FacilityId
WHERE 
(
 (StartDateTime >= @StartDateTime AND StartDateTime < @EndDateTime) OR (EndDateTime > @StartDateTime AND StartDateTime < @StartDateTime)
) AND b.TenantId IS NULL
```

However, If I understand correctly, I would not use this code and I will check first instead of use Insert query directly. 
For example, use this select query instead of insert, if it is not zero you do not have to run your insert query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Bookings 
WHERE 
    TenantId = @TenantId AND FacilityId = @FacilityId AND
    (
        (StartDateTime >= @StartDateTime AND StartDateTime < @EndDateTime) OR 
        (EndDateTime > @StartDateTime AND StartDateTime < @StartDateTime)
    )
```

Comment: Use of `EXISTS` can be important to facilitating locks and unlike `COUNT(*)` it stops at the first yes answer row returnable (also called a boolean or `bit` in `SQL Server`). Much better to use a yes or no answer than start an expensive insert statement, too as you say.

Comment: Thanks purevsuren & @Clifton for some SQL syntax tips but question is more concerned with concurrency. If userA and userB both try and do a INSERT at the same time could you end up with two entries because of the of a gap between the SELECT and then the INSERT ... or am I just being over careful

Comment: You can actually set the priority transaction locks to decide that too

Comment: Yeah, we can use `EXISTS` but, sub-query always bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT EXISTS for validation purpose. It is faster way than checking existance using COUNT.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Bookings as b WHERE b.FacilityID = @FacilityId 
                        AND ((StartDateTime >= @StartDateTime AND StartDateTime < @EndDateTime) OR (EndDateTime > @StartDateTime AND StartDateTime < @StartDateTime)) )
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.Bookings (TenantId, FacilityId, UnitId, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, ...)
    SELECT  @TenantId, @FacilityId, @UnitId, @StartDateTime, @EndDateTime, ...;
END
ELSE
    PRINT   'Facility is already booked for this duration.';
```

Comment: I always consider `*` to be of great significance, so using it within an [NOT] EXISTS statement is odd since it is ignored. SQL Server only cares about if a row is returned, not the columns. It is for this reason why you will often see SELECT 1 which makes the point clear.